# Multiple search boxes for a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, search, box

what I currently trying to achieve it's a group of incremental (I hope that's the right word) search boxes. I'm trying to make a website about food recipes, what I want it's for people to be able to search recipes based on the ingredients they currently have, so instead of having 10 or 15 search boxes cluttering everything I want only 1 search box appearing at a time.

What I'm thinking it's that if you fill the first search bar the second will show up and so on.

What would I need to achieve this? Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input id="1" class="search" type="text" style="display: inline">
<input id="2" class="search" type="text">
<input id="3" class="search" type="text">
```

CSS:

```
.search {
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.search').each(function() {
        var nextNum = 1 + (+$(this).attr('id'));
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('#' + nextNum).show();
        });
    });
});
```

---

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skqsu3we/).

Comment: Wow, thanks! I imagined that it would be something more difficult but it's very straightforward. My JS and Jquery knowledge it's very limited so I thought it would a lot more complicated.